# All the solutions of the 2-dim PDE $-\Delta u=\lambda e^{u}$ with boundary conditions $u=0$ are like $\log \frac{8b}{(1+\lambda b r^{2})^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

It's clear that with the radial change of variables $r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$, the solutions of the form $\log\left(\frac{8b}{(1+\lambda b r^{2})^2}\right)$ solve the equation $-\Delta u=\lambda e^{u}$ with boundary conditions $u=0$ in $\partial B_{1}(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$, where $$b=\frac{4-\lambda\pm\sqrt{16-8\lambda}}{\lambda^2}.$$But I have to show that *all* the solutions of the PDE have that form. In the book I am following (*Stable solutions of elliptic partial differential equations*, L. Dupaigne, section 2.3, proposition 2.3.1) I am told that as the ODE $$-u''-\frac{N-1}{r}u'=\lambda e^{u}$$ has at most one solution, then it follows that all the solutions to $-\Delta u=\lambda e^{u}$ must have that logarithmic form. But I don't understand the reason of that ODE, just have no idea.

Any help with why that and why it gives the form of the solutions for the PDE? Thank you!

Comment: If you asking where the ODE comes from, it comes from [converting the Laplacian into polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions) and then noting that $u$ is independent of the angle $\theta$ so that derivatives with respect to the angle vanish. We make this coordinate change because the Laplacian is _invariant with respect to rotations_. Just so you know, the ODE you wrote above is [for the $N$ dimensional PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#N_dimensions).

Comment: That was exactly my question!! Thank you very much for the help.